# Proving Not (Elem x xs) when x and xs are statically known

Tags: idris, theorem-proving

In Chapter 9 of [Type Driven Development with Idris](https://www.manning.com/books/type-driven-development-with-idris), we are introduced to the `Elem` predicate with constructors `Here` and `There` for proving that an element is a member of a vector. e.g.

```
oneInVector : Elem 1 [1, 2, 3]
oneInVector = Here

twoInVector : Elem 2 [1, 2, 3]
twoInVector = There Here
```

I'm wondering how to show that an element is *not* in a vector. It should perhaps be by providing a solution to this type:

```
notThere : Elem 4 [1, 2, 3] -> Void
notThere = ?rhs
```

Expression/Proof search does not come up with the answer in this case, giving:

```
notThere : Elem 4 [1,2,3] -> Void
notThere = \__pi_arg => ?rhs1
```

[Scanning through the library for `Data.Vect`](https://github.com/idris-lang/Idris-dev/blob/fe1d4700cc10948280a7f330babb12fd2a66a147/libs/base/Data/Vect.idr#L597), these definitions look useful (but I'm not sure how to connect the dots):

```
||| Nothing can be in an empty Vect
noEmptyElem : {x : a} -> Elem x [] -> Void
noEmptyElem Here impossible

Uninhabited (Elem x []) where
  uninhabited = noEmptyElem
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `Elem` relation is `Dec`idable (if the element type has `Dec`idable `Eq`uality itself), using `isElem`:

```
isElem : DecEq a => (x : a) -> (xs : Vect n a) -> Dec (Elem x xs)
```

The idea is to use `isElem 4 [1, 2, 3]` to have Idris compute the proof of `Not (Elem 4 [1, 2, 3])`. We'll need to build up some machinery similar to Agda's [`Relation.Nullary.Decidable.toWitnessFalse`](https://agda.github.io/agda-stdlib/Relation.Nullary.Decidable.html#1354) so that we can extract proofs from (negative) `Dec` results:

```
fromFalse : (d : Dec p) -> {auto isFalse : decAsBool d = False} -> Not p
fromFalse (Yes _) {isFalse = Refl} impossible
fromFalse (No contra) = contra
```

and then we can use this in your `notThere` definition:

```
notThere : Not (Elem 4 [1, 2, 3])
notThere = fromFalse (isElem 4 [1, 2, 3])
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than specifying my own rhs for `notThere`, it's better to use Idris' editor support:

Starting with:

```
notThere : Elem 4 [1, 2, 3] -> Void
```

Add definition on `notThere`:

```
notThere : Elem 4 [1, 2, 3] -> Void
notThere x = ?notThere_rhs
```

Case split on `x`:

```
notThere : Elem 4 [1, 2, 3] -> Void
notThere (There later) = ?notThere_rhs
```

Case split on `later`:

```
notThere : Elem 4 [1, 2, 3] -> Void
notThere (There (There later)) = ?notThere_rhs
```

Case split on `later`:

```
notThere : Elem 4 [1, 2, 3] -> Void
notThere (There (There There later))) = ?notThere_rhs
```

Case split on `later`:

```
notThere : Elem 4 [1,2,3] -> Void
notThere (There (There (There Here))) impossible
notThere (There (There (There (There _)))) impossible
```

This definition is total and so we're done:

```
*Elem> :total notThere
Main.notThere is Total
```

I'd still be interested if there's a nicer solution that uses the `noEmptyElem` and/or `uninhabited` from `Data.Vect`.